# view is distorted after using activeadmin, says translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, activeadmin

I have used twitter-bootstrap gem to make a store application. It was working fine until I added the activeadmin gem.

The view of the admin home page has a line:
Store Title

and the

```
"translation_missing"
```

is almost every where and the view is distorted.

These are the things I did:
add this line to my gem file:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
```

and then run this:

```
rails generate active_admin:install
rake db:migrate
rails s
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, go to `/config/locales/en.yml`, and add the latest en.yml from the [active_admin repo](https://raw.github.com/gregbell/active_admin/master/config/locales/en.yml) to the end (or replace the same block for `en: active_admin` block if it already exists in your local en.yml file)

This worked for me. ActiveAdmin was missing some translations (probably due to a Gem conflict) and this fixes that.

Comment: Confirmed to work for me, although it was working fine and all of a sudden stopped.  Also the link has changed to [here](https://raw.github.com/gregbell/active_admin/master/config/locales/en.yml)